# Return results of second query if first query returns nothing otherwise return nothing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with generating a query that does the following

```
If query1 returns 0 rows
    then return results of query2
else
    return nothing
```

UNION and COALESCE are not answers

The first query looks like this:

```
SELECT aa.id from A aa JOIN B bb on aa.id=bb.pid where bb.pid = 10 and aa.sid IS NOT NULL
```

The second query looks like this:

```
SELECT aa.id from A aa JOIN B bb on aa.id=bb.pid where bb.pid = 10 and aa.sid IS NULL
```

I can already run the second query with the sid column returned and just check for it's existence in the results, but I would love to figure out how to do this as a single query.

Comment: `select ... "query2" where not exists (select ... "query1")`

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know

Comment: Boomity!  That works.  If you will put that as an answer I will check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to filter for NOT EXISTS query1-result, something like:

```
select ... "query2" where not exists (select ... "query1")
```

Which in your case would be:

```
SELECT aa.id from A aa JOIN B bb on aa.id=bb.pid
where bb.pid = 10 and aa.sid IS NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT aa.id from A aa JOIN B bb on aa.id=bb.pid
      where bb.pid = 10 and aa.sid IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 2 queries, do it all in one.

From Oracle 12, you can use `ORDER BY` to order the non-`NULL` rows first and then the `NULL` rows second and then `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to get all the rows that  are non-`NULL` and then if they do not exist then the `NULL` rows then you can use an inline view to filter to only show the `NULL` `sid` rows:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT aa.id, aa.sid
  FROM   A aa
         JOIN B bb
         on aa.id=bb.pid
  WHERE  bb.pid = 10
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN aa.sid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
)
WHERE  sid IS NULL;
```

If you are using Oracle 11 or earlier then you can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT aa.id,
         aa.sid,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN aa.sid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC)
           AS rnk
  FROM   A aa
         JOIN B bb
         on aa.id=bb.pid
  WHERE  bb.pid = 10
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
AND    sid IS NULL;
```

or the analytic `COUNT` function to count the number of non-`NULL` `sid` values:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT aa.id,
         aa.sid,
         COUNT(aa.sid) OVER () AS num_sid
  FROM   A aa
         JOIN B bb
         on aa.id=bb.pid
  WHERE  bb.pid = 10
)
WHERE  num_sid = 0;
```

or you can use `NOT EXISTS` (although this will be less efficient than the previous queries as it will read from the tables twice, whereas the previous queries only read from the table once):

```sql
SELECT aa.id
FROM   A aa
       JOIN B bb
       on aa.id=bb.pid
WHERE  bb.pid = 10
AND    aa.sid IS NULL
AND    NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   A aa
                JOIN B bb
                on aa.id=bb.pid
         WHERE  bb.pid = 10
         AND    aa.sid IS NOT NULL
       );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EB9MPTLU)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.  I wanted nothing to be returned at all if any sids were set.  But thanks for the fiddle link.  I now have that bookmarked

Comment: @lkreinitz Fixed, minor change to add a filter but exactly the same technique.